# CakePHP 3 - Cannot describe sessions. It has 0 columns. Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, session, azure, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP App that is currently accessing the database via Azure SQL. Below, is the connection string

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
        'persistent' => true,
        'host' => 'XXX.database.windows.net',
        'port' => '1433',
        'encoding' => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,
        'username' => 'XXX',
        'password' => 'XXX',
        'database' => 'DBXXX',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
```

I am using Database Sessions.

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'database'
]
```

I am able to get the db connected. However, I got this error below,

**Cannot describe sessions. It has 0 columns.**

Sessions table definitely has columns and data. But I not sure why it states 0 columns? Not only the sessions table. I've other tables that have columns and data too. But it just states **Cannot describe tableName. It has 0 columns.** Anybody facing the same issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this issue today, and managed to find a solution for my circumstances. This may differ for you, or others who encounter this error, but this is one permutation of it I thought worth documenting for others to rule out.

I had an existing schema in a postgres database. This was populated with seed data. Both of these operations were performed independent of CakePHP 3.x. This schema Cake is connecting to and the API being produced through Cake are exploratory prototypes to evaluate whether to go ahead with Cake or Laravel on our project so, things such as best practice and being unable to tear down and recreate and repopulate a schema weren't constraining me.

#### Cake Conventions

Cake has some fairly strict naming [conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) [Documentation for how to follow *'CakePHP Conventions over Configuration'*]. I suggest reading through the sections relating to Models and Databases and their naming conventions. Ultimately, this turned out to be the root of my issue.

I've been producing the schema through PowerArchitect to speed up going from a conceptual ERD to the DDL SQL script for testing various tools and frameworks. The issue here is, it's a pain to handle collisions between entity key names. For example, where two entities both have `id` fields. Therefore, for the sake of a quick prototype, it was much easier for me to name them `<table-name>_id` despite my preference for naming them `id`.

For example:

We have two tables - `person` with a PK of `person_id` and `user_account` with key `account_id`. Our FK constraint exists on `user_account` (`person_id` is FK on `user_account` as 1-n).

The cause of this I believe I found was that when commanding Cake to bake with `bin/cake bake all user_account`, the snake case of the tables `account_id` PK indicates to Cake that `account_id` is a FK to another table named `account`, existing on the `user_account` table. From my understanding, the same would happen if named `user_account_id`. This is when the `Cannot describe account. It has 0 columns.` bubbled up at runtime as Cake was searching for a table `account` with an `id` field.

In my case, it was easy enough to tear down the schema and edit the table names and keys accordingly to better meet Cakes conventions, then recreate and populate it.

If this isn't an option, it seems it's possible to [manually map table names to Models](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html) [*'Table Objects'* for modelling database entities], or [bake your application in a modular manner](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html) [How to Bake boilerplate with *Bake*] to have greater control over components and their dependancies. Since you specify you're using SQLserver, it may also be possible its conventions are interfering with that of Cake. You might find [this Github thread](https://github.com/snelg/cakephp-3-oracle/issues/6) relating to the error being caused by Oracle vs Cake conventions helpful. Specifically, this answer from 'snelg':

> Oracle's "everything is capitalized!" is clashing with Cake's auto-inflection.
>   If you try to bake something like "SomeTable", then Cake will look for a table named "some_table".
>   If you try to bake "USERS", then Cake will look for a table named "u_s_e_r_s".
>   You can overcome this first problem by simply typing the table name in lower case.

Comment: Another important thing: BelongsToMany requires table name to be `somethings_somethingelses` in alphabetical order.